# Why can I use initializer lists on the right-hand side of operator += but not operator+?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, initializer-list

This is a follow-up to [an earlier question about why I can't use a brace-enclosed initializer as an argument to `operator+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191661/why-cant-i-use-an-brace-enclosed-list-as-an-operand-to-an-overloaded-operator), which was resolved by looking at [this earlier question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators).

Consider the following C++ code, which you can [try live at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/xrS0HK):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

struct AddInitializerList {
    void operator+= (initializer_list<int> values) {
        // Do nothing   
    }
    
    void operator+ (initializer_list<int> values) {
        // Do nothing
    }
};

int main() {
    AddInitializerList adder;
    adder += {1, 2, 3};  // Totally legit
    adder +  {1, 2, 3};  // Not okay!
    
    return 0;
}
```

The line in `main` that uses `operator+` with a brace-enclosed initializer list does not compile (and, after asking that earlier question, I now know why this is). However, I'm confused why the code that uses `operator+=` in `main` does indeed compile just fine.

I'm confused as to precisely why I can overload `+=` and have it work just fine, while overloading `+` doesn't seem to work here. Is there a particular provision in the standard that permits brace-enclosed initializers in the context of the `+=` operator but not the `+` operator? Or is this just a weird compiler quirk?

Comment: You didn't specify your compiler, but I reproduce this fail with gcc 6.3.1, which barks at me with "error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token".

Comment: I would guess that curly braces is supported for all assignment operators.

Comment: And `adder +  initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3};` works just fine.

Comment: Aye, `adder.operator+({1, 2, 3});` works as well. This is interesting. I can't seem to find any ambiguity with `adder + { 1, 2, 3 }`. Wonder why this was decided.

Comment: Yes, that guess was correct. C++14 §5.17/9.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators)  (which is linked from the question you linked to).

The language grammar only allows a braced list in certain grammatical contexts, not in place of an arbitrary expression.  That list includes the right-hand side of assignment operators, but NOT the right-hand side of operators in general.

`+=` is an assignment operator, `+` is not.

The grammar for assignment expressions is:

> ```
>   assignment-expression:
>      conditional-expression
>      logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
>      throw-expression
>   assignment-operator: one of
>       = *= *= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ^= |=
> ```

Comment: @NeilButterworth That is covered in the Q/A I linked to

Comment: Well, that would definitely explain things. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. The question is why the grammar allows brace init list for `+=` but not for `+`. Listing the particular grammar rule just says the OP is not mistaken about what the grammar allows.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The OP, verbatim, "Is there a particular provision in the standard that permits brace-enclosed initializers in the context of the += operator but not the + operator?"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question you're asking is a really, really good one. I've read some other answers quoting folks who say the decision was primarily based on making the parser easier to implement, so I suspect that's what's going on here (and why I didn't ask that question specifically).

Answer (score 11):

C++14 §5.17/9:

> **”** A *braced-init-list* may appear on the right-hand side of
>
> - an assignment to a scalar, in which case the initializer list shall have at most a single element. The meaning of `x={v}`, where `T` is the scalar type of the expression `x`, is that of `x=T{v}`. The meaning of `x={}` is `x=T{}`.
> - an assignment to an object of class type, in which case the initializer list is passed as the argument to the assignment operator function selected by overload resolution (13.5.3, 13.3).

This applies to *a*`+=`*b* via its $5.7/7 equivalence to *a*`=`*a*`+`*b* (except that *a* is evaluated only once for `+=`). Put another way, due to a comment by M.M., because of the equivalence for the built-in operators `+=` is regarded as an assignment operator, and not a special update operator.
Hence the quoted text above about “assignment” applies to `+=`.

Comment: It is because `a += b` matches the grammar for assignment expressions, not because of equivalence to `a = a + b`  (which is not even true in the case of overloaded operators). The 5.17/7 only refers to the non-overloaded case; see point 3 at the start of clause 5

Comment: @M.M. You're right, and that's a trivial observation. You could make it more interesting by claiming that the standard has a defect in section $5, where it fails to to cover user defined `+=`.

Answer (score 7):

`+=` operator is a *compound assignment*. The standard explicitly permits initializer lists on the right-hand side of assignments:

> §8.5.4/1 [...] Note: List-initialization can be used
>
> ...
>
> — on the right-hand side of an assignment (5.17)

§5.17 talks about all assignments, including compound ones:

> assignment-expression:
>    - conditional-expression
>    - logical-or-expression *assignment-operator* initializer-clause
>    - throw-expression
>
> assignment-operator: one of
>   `=` `*=` `/=` `%=` `+=` `-=` `>>=` `<<=` `&=` `ˆ=` `|=`