# Why doesn't C++ allow implicit list initialization in the conditional operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, conditional-operator, list-initialization

This code compiles:

```
std::string f(bool a, std::string const& b)
{
    if (a) return b;
    return {};
}
```

This code also compiles:

```
std::string f(bool a, std::string const& b)
{
    return a ? b : std::string{};
}
```

This code does not compile:

```
std::string f(bool a, std::string const& b)
{
    return a ? b : {};
}
```

Given that both result values of the `?:` operator are required to be the same type, why doesn't it infer the type like it does in the first example?

---

It appears that this question might have a similar answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602382/why-can-i-use-initializer-lists-on-the-right-hand-side-of-operator-but-not-op) (which essentially boils down to "because nobody thought about it when writing the language specification").  However I still think it's useful to retain this question as the question itself is different, it's still sufficiently surprising, and the other wouldn't come up in searches for this issue.

Comment: Both types are required to be convertible to the same type.  `{}` doesnt have a type.

Comment: clang says `{}` is an initalizer list (which cannot be used here) live: https://godbolt.org/z/imYL6q

Comment: Replacing `{}` with `std::initializer_list<char>()` also compiles.

Comment: Maybe this question could be turned into a language proposal

Comment: @miral: The correct term is "list initialization". That's what the standard calls it; you will find nothing in the standard about "uniform initialization".

Answer (score 6):

A braced initializer is not an expression and thus it has no type. See:

https://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html

A braced initializer is a grammatical construct with special rules in the standard, explicitly specifying allowed use and type deduction. These special rules are needed exactly because braced initializers have no type. Using them in `?:` statements is not specified, and thus the program is ill-formed.

If you really need to hear the man himself say it three times in a row before you believe it, then:

https://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU?t=1792

Comment: but `return {};` works

Comment: @xaxxon With `return {}` the return type of the function is known.

Comment: with `return a ? b : {};` the return type of the function isn't known?

Comment: @xaxxon The return type is known, but the type of the `?:` isn't known.

Comment: `return a ? b : "";` compiles, as does `return a ? b : std::initializer_list<char>{};`.  So clearly the compiler is allowed to perform construction/conversion based on the declared return type and/or the type of `b`.  So `{}` should be equally valid.

Comment: @Miral `""` has a type.  `std::initializer_list<char>{}` also has a type. `{}` doesn't.

Comment: Correct, but that means it's compatible with any type, which is how it works in return statements, arguments, and initialisation to begin with.

Comment: @Miral: "*it's compatible with any type*" No, it isn't. It is a grammatical construct which, in certain locations, can be used to initialize a prvalue of a type. It isn't "compatible" with anything.

Comment: @Miral That's because the standard specifically allows for that. Braced initializers have no type, and thus their allowed use needs to be explicitly specified by the standard. Using it in `?:` was never specified and so the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @NikosC.: It should be noted that braced-init-lists do not have a type because they're *not expressions*. They are a distinct grammatical construct from expressions. So asking them about type is like asking them about their "value" or any other thing associated with expressions.

Comment: @xaxxon the language specification for the `return` statement explicitly says that the next thing can either be an expression, or a braced list, and goes on to define what will happen if a braced list is provided (namely, that the braced list is taken as initializer for copy-initialization of the result object)

Comment: I get that it's not a compiler error.   But the other way to interpret the question is "does it actually make sense as a requirement?"  or "is there a technical reason it cannot be done?"

Comment: As moderator stated "It appears that this question might have a similar answer to this (which essentially boils down to "because nobody thought about it when writing the language specification")." I don't see how it's duplicate. Nor I don't see reason it can't be done as type can be guessed from one of operands.